# split cell at special character if comma found after first word

Tags: r

hi i've got some budget data with names and titles that read "Last, First - Title" and other rows in same column position that read "anything really - ,asd;flkajsd". I'd like to split the column IF first word ends in a "," at the "-" position that follows it.

ive tried this:

```
C22$ITEM2 <- ifelse(grepl(",", C22$ITEM), C22$ITEM,  NA)
test <- str_split_fixed(C22$ITEM2, "-", 2)
C22 <- cbind(C22, test)
```

but i'm getting other cells with commas elsewhere, need to limit to just "if first word ends in comma"

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(data = c("Doe, John - Mr", "Anna, Anna - Ms", " ,asd;flkajsd"))
data
data %>%
  # first word must ed with a
  filter(data %>% str_detect("^[A-z]+a")) %>%
  separate(data, into = c("Last", "First", "Title"), sep = "[,-]") %>%
  mutate_all(str_trim)
# A tibble: 1 × 3
#  Last  First Title
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 Anna  Anna  Ms
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `extract` to do this - capture the regex pattern as two groups (`(...)`) where the first group would return word (`\\w+`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by a `,`, zero or more space (`\\s*`), another word (`\\w+`), then the `-` (preceding or succeeding zero or more space and the second capture group with the word (`\\w+`) before the end (`$`) of the string

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
extract(C22, ITEM, into = c("Name", "Title"), 
      "^(\\w+,\\s*\\w+)\\s*-\\s*(\\w+)$") %>%
   mutate(Name = coalesce(Name, ITEM), .keep = 'unused')
```

NOTE: The `mutate` is added in case the regex didn't match and return `NA` elements, we `coalesce` with the original column to return the value that corresponds to NA

Comment: this really helped me understand the regex underlying this kind of search, although i couldnt seem to get the above code to work properly (what i end up is simply a new column .keep: unused). i was able to take the search pattern in @danlooo 's answer and use it in my original grepl but it is not pretty. this kind of search is new to me so your help has been appreciated!

Comment: @gered I was using the example from other post and it is working for me though.  It is better to post a small reproducible example and expected output so that it can be tested. thanks

Comment: @gered Regarding the `.keep`, it could be an issue related to your `dplyr` version i.e. if it is an older version, it may not work